# Pasting numbers from list into column in R function

Tags: r, parsing, numeric

I have a function used to import quiz data from a course, clean it, and make some calculations. The beginning of the whole script starts off by reading in the folder names (one for each of the 9 weeks, each folder containing 3 files) as a list called unitNames. The names are structured as "Week # (Chapter #)". Some of the numbers are single digit and some are double digit, for both week and chapter.

Ideally, as each of the files within the folders is read in, I would like the corresponding week and chapter numbers from unitNames pasted in as columns called "week" and "chapter".

Here is a sample of the code to add context:

```
     myDir="~/Dropbox/Online Learning Data/psychCourse" #state where the files are housed
    unitNames = list.files(path=myDir, full.names=FALSE) #list the folder names
    print(unitNames)
    >"Week 11 (Chapter 14)" "Week 12 (Chapter 15)" "Week 2 (Chapter 2)"   "Week 3 (Chapter 3)"   "Week 4 (Chapter 5)"   "Week 7 (Chapter 6)"   "Week 8 (Chapter 12)"  "Week 9 (Chapter 13)" 
    
    courseData=NULL #create a data "shell" to then add all the file data to
    
    for (unit in 1:length(unitNames)) #for each unit in unitNames, read in the 3 files and run the merge function (which combines the 3 files and makes calculations and repeats and binds for all units
    {
      courseData=rbind(courseData,mergeData(myDir, unitNames[unit]))
    }
```

Any help with this is much appreciated and I'm happy to supply more of the actual mergeData function if helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With connections you cam easily do most of the work. Read the vector `unitNames` as a [`textConnection`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/textconnections.html) and remove the close parenthesis. Then coerce the two columns to integer and assign the required names.

```r
unitNames <- c("Week 11 (Chapter 14)", "Week 12 (Chapter 15)", "Week 2 (Chapter 2)",   "Week 3 (Chapter 3)",   "Week 4 (Chapter 5)",   "Week 7 (Chapter 6)",   "Week 8 (Chapter 12)",  "Week 9 (Chapter 13)")

df1 <- read.table(textConnection(unitNames), sep = " ")[c(2, 4)]
df1$V4 <- sub("\\)", "", df1$V4)
df1[] <- lapply(df1, as.integer)
names(df1) <- c("Week", "Chapter")
df1
#>   Week Chapter
#> 1   11      14
#> 2   12      15
#> 3    2       2
#> 4    3       3
#> 5    4       5
#> 6    7       6
#> 7    8      12
#> 8    9      13
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>